# How to upload a video from gallery in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am building an app when a user clicks the button, it goes to gallery and select any of the video in gallery and then returns back to the main screen in app and plays the video automatically. Below is code i have tried.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Image App Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xff476cfb),
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  File _imageFile;
  Future getVideo() async{
    File image;
    image=await ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _imageFile=image;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Image Upload"),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("Video"),
                  onPressed: (){
                    getVideo();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
}
```

Comment: so where is the problem, just upload _imageFile in the multipart form to the server using your API

Comment: i think you're asking on how to preview the video

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Display video using [video player](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/play-video)

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() => runApp(VideoPlayerApp());

class VideoPlayerApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Video Player Demo',
      home: VideoPlayerScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class VideoPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  VideoPlayerScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoPlayerScreenState createState() => _VideoPlayerScreenState();
}

class _VideoPlayerScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  File videoFile;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // Create and store the VideoPlayerController. The VideoPlayerController
    // offers several different constructors to play videos from assets, files,
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Ensure disposing of the VideoPlayerController to free up resources.
    _controller.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Butterfly Video'),
      ),
      // Use a FutureBuilder to display a loading spinner while waiting for the
      // VideoPlayerController to finish initializing.
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Visibility(
        visible: _controller != null,
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              // If the VideoPlayerController has finished initialization, use
              // the data it provides to limit the aspect ratio of the video.
              return AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                // Use the VideoPlayer widget to display the video.
                child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
              );
            } else {
              // If the VideoPlayerController is still initializing, show a
              // loading spinner.
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
      RaisedButton(
        child: Text("Video"),
        onPressed: () {
          getVideo();
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
  floatingActionButton: _controller == null
      ? null
      : FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Wrap the play or pause in a call to `setState`. This ensures the
            // correct icon is shown.
            setState(() {
              // If the video is playing, pause it.
              if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
                _controller.pause();
              } else {
                // If the video is paused, play it.
                _controller.play();
              }
            });
          },
          // Display the correct icon depending on the state of the player.
          child: Icon(
            _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
          ),
        ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  Future getVideo() async {
    Future<File> _videoFile =
    ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);
_videoFile.then((file) async {
  setState(() {
    videoFile = file;
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.file(videoFile);

    // Initialize the controller and store the Future for later use.
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();

    // Use the controller to loop the video.
    _controller.setLooping(true);
  });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not using any api or url, i want to fetch video from phone gallery and show video on main screen of the app

Comment: When i click the button for the video it takes full screen while playing the video, Could you please show me the half of the screen for video play.

Comment: wrap the FutureBuilder in a container and set the height to whatever you want

Answer (score 4):

you can use this widget from [image_picker](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/main/packages/image_picker/image_picker/example/lib/main.dart)
answer based n image_picker example

```
 Widget _previewVideo() {
    final Text retrieveError = _getRetrieveErrorWidget();
    if (retrieveError != null) {
      return retrieveError;
    }
    if (_controller == null) {
      return const Text(
        'You have not yet picked a video',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    }
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: AspectRatioVideo(_controller),
    );
  }
```

//how to pass video to preview

```
 Center(
    child: Platform.isAndroid
        ? FutureBuilder<void>(
            future: retrieveLostData(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return const Text(
                    'You have not yet picked an image.',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  );
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  return isVideo ? _previewVideo() : _previewImage();
                default:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text(
                      'Pick image/video error: ${snapshot.error}}',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    );
                  } else {
                    return const Text(
                      'You have not yet picked an image.',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    );
                  }
              }
            },
          )
        : (isVideo ? _previewVideo() : _previewImage()),
  ),
```